# Subitem indentation

Tags: lists, itemize

How can I ensure that when the text goes on a new line it starts at the level of the \Subitem instead of the intendation level of \item as it does it now?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\newcommand{\Subitem}[1]{
    {\setlength\itemindent{15pt} \item[-] #1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item{1. Klasse:}
    \Subitem{Zahlen: Zahlbereiche, Irrationalität, Potenzen und Wurzeln sind sehr wichtig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Why you not nested `itemize` in `itemize`? Doing this, you will be on more correct way to solve your problem (if I understood what you like to achieve. BTW, your document example contain error: `itemize` is not terminated by `\end{itemize}`-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways.  I recommend the second, in which you use nested `itemize` environments.  If you insist on using a macro `\Subitem`, then include the inner environment in the definition of `\Subitem`.  As Don notes in a comment, the use of adjacent `\Subitem`s will create too much vertical space, since a new sub-environment is created for each invocation.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\newcommand{\Subitem}[1]{\begin{itemize}
    \item[-] #1\end{itemize}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item{1. Klasse:}
    \Subitem{Zahlen: Zahlbereiche, Irrationalität, Potenzen und Wurzeln sind sehr wichtig}
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}
  \item{1. Klasse:}
    \begin{itemize}
     \item Zahlen: Zahlbereiche, Irrationalität, Potenzen und Wurzeln sind sehr wichtig
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although your macro will put too much space between adjacent `\Subitem` commands. Much better to just use the nested `itemize` environments.

Comment: @DonHosek Absolutely true.